# Boot loop, never got past Windows logo when installing from a USB drive

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, bios

I'm trying to get Windows 10 on an old PC (Xeon E5430, OEM motherboard G41 chipset) using a bootable USB drive I created with Microsoft Media Creation Tool. On the only HDD connected to the PC, I already had Ubuntu installed.

When booting from the USB drive, it will show a blinking cursor on top left corner for approx 30s, then the Windows logo for a brief moment, before it automatically restarts. I never got past the Windows logo to any menu or option screen.

Some interesting thing is, in my BIOS boot option, I don't have any UEFI or legacy BIOS selection. Also, under "Boot device priority", I only have one option, which is whatever set as "1st drive" in the "Hard disk drives" section.

Comment: Mostlikely this hardware is not supported by WIndows 10 - and it wouldn't run in any meaningfull way even if you were to install it.

Comment: That CPU dates from 2007 (Introduction date Nov 12, 2007) which predates Windows 10 by 8 years. I suggest you forget this project as the outcome will not be good.

Comment: Thanks, I Googled a bit more and found someone with the same CPU and the same problem, it seems like a hardware limit after all. Bummer cause I was hoping to gift my parents this PC. I managed to get Win10 on stuff as old as Pentium E6700 before though.

Comment: @Dan i think something wrong with win USB - use WoeUSB {https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB} to create win bootable usb on linux; also you can try 8,1 iso - https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows8ISO; also make sure iso aren't corrupted

Comment: @Madhubala I just plugged that same USB drive into my main PC, it boots without issue. Just for the sake of fun I'll install Windows on that SSD from the Xeon machine using my main PC, and plug it back in the old one to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're creating your install media with an MBR not GPT partition scheme.

I think that the built-in way to create installation media uses GPT so you will need a third party tool to force the USB to use MBR parition scheme. (I know Rufus has this option, but others probably do too.)